# mySQL: exclude user with current ID from query results

Tags: php, mysql

I've noticed that the site's user profile edit form allows logged in user to take other user's id and e-mail, which is not good.

To avoid such behavior I've made the query `SELECT * FROM users WHERE (username='$username' OR email='$email');` which gets all usernames, all e-mails and then PHP successfully prevents the form execution if such username or e-mail already exists.

But I've noticed that this query also gets currently logged in user's credentials and prevents the user from changing its other data in case username or e-mail are unchanged.

I've decided to exclude the current user by its ID.

I've tried `SELECT * FROM users WHERE (username='$username' OR email='$email' OR id!='$id');` to exclude the current user but it still exists and prevents changes in its own profile.

What could be wrong with my query? Any help is greatly appreciated!

---

*I actually have two same tables for users, the second one is for users who still have not activated their profiles. But I suppose there is no reason to search for ID's in that second table as the current user definitely can not wait for activation of its account. Also ID's in those two tables don't match anyway so in case I should exclude a user from the second database I must find a different approach. But I hope I shouldn't.*

Comment: If you want username and email to be unique, put a `UNIQUE` constraint on the column storing username and email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know you specific case:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE (username='$username' OR email='$email' ) AND id<>'$id'
```

This query find by email or username and not retrieve by this ID